# Linear Report in Acumatica

Tags: erp, acumatica

I want three column report..
For example

```
 name email             name email                 name  email
----- -----             ---- -------               ----- ------
 n1    e1               n4   e4                    n7    e7
 n2    e2               n5   e5
 n3    e3               n6   e6
```

Is there any way to implement such report with Acumatica ?

Answer (score 1):

It's called a tabular report. There are 14 reports bundled with the application which use this mode. You can check out the following reports if you want to get an idea of how to use it: CR.62.41.60, DR.66.00.45. Take a look at the TabularReport and TabularFreeze properties once in the report designer.

Comment: I have found some other helps as well. it required at least one Grouping But, I have not any Group. Second records need to move on next column once it reach to end of the page.